# SOLVED: Include (Sub-)Sectionnumber in pdf bookmark

Tags: sectioning, formatting, pdf, bookmarks, subsection

I am writing my homework in latex just for fun and get better at it.

Where my sections are exercises and my subsections I want to be parts of the exercise.

The format for subsection should be `SecNum.\alph{SubSecNum}`,
while section should be the default arabic numbering.

1. I want this format for the the ToC and as label for all Subsection.
2. The subsection label should be prefixed in the final pdf bookmark

---

I can get the labels of subsections to be of that format with

```latex
% make the subsections be numbered in a specific format
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection .\alph{subsection})}
\begin{document}
\section{Ex 1}
\subsection{whatever}
% should appear as "1.a whatever" in Pdf-Bookmark
\end{document}
```

I saw other methodes with `\titleformat` and eddeding toc entry labeling
but didn't want to adjust both when the format changes.

Comment: do not put solutions in the question, you can post (and accept) an answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Adding:

```
\bookmarksetup{
  numbered,
 }
```

added the number used by toc to the bookmark name like I wanted